# How can I write out the path of 0 size files

Tags: path, size

How can I modify my query (below) to get the (absolute) path of all the 0 sized files within a directory?

```
find ./ -size 0 -print
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working here ? This would indeed recursively list down all empty files in a directory

Comment: can u share your desired sample output...?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Do you need the full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `find` does print the path, the whole **relative** path from where you called the command.

But if you need the whole **absolute** path to each file, just use:

```
find "$PWD" -size 0 -print
```

That's it.